# Чекбокс "Выбрать все"

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю парсер сайта.
Пользователь должен отмечать разделы, которые нужно пропарсить. Должен быть главный чекбокс, который может выбрать/снять все разделы сразу.

Разделы задаю в таком виде, чтобы можно было их прибиндить к `ListBox`.

Где `Key` — название раздела, `Value` — нужно ли его парсить.

```
    public class Chapter
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Chapter> SiteChapters { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Chapter>()
    {
        new Chapter() {Key = "Раздел1", Value = true},
        new Chapter() {Key = "Раздел2", Value = true},
        new Chapter() {Key = "Раздел3", Value = true},
        new Chapter() {Key = "Раздел4", Value = true},
        new Chapter() {Key = "Раздел5", Value = true},
    };
```

Все это дело привязываю так:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Background="#eaeeff" 
        BorderBrush="#e1efff" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
        Padding="10,10">
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbSelectAll" Content="Выбрать все" />
    </Border>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SiteChapters}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Value}"
                      Margin="5,3,0,2" >
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding Path="Value" />
                            <Binding ElementName="cbSelectAll" Path="IsChecked" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

И использую такой конвертер:

```
class MultiBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isSelectAll = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);
        bool isNull = values[1] == null;

        if (isSelectAll)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!isNull)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[2] { value, null };
    }
}
```

Отрабатывает это все так. Для наглядности вывожу значение вместо названия. Видно, что значение раздела меняется только при клике на конкретный чекбокс, но не на главный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не проходит ощущение, что я реализую это вообще в корне неправильно.
Подскажите, как можно сделать такое?

---

Можно сделать команды для главного чекбоса, в которых будет перебираться коллекция разделов и устанавливать всем true/false. Но как тогда сделать если выбрана часть разделов, то у главного чекбокса было "третье состояние" `null`, т.е. был квадратик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал для разделов отдельную VM.
В ней сделал свойство, которое хранит значение выбраны ли все разделы:

```
public bool? IsSelectedAll 
{
    get { return _isSelectedAll; }
    set
    {
        _isSelectedAll = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Затем к чекбоксу, который выделяет все разделы прибиндил команду, в которой проходится коллекция с разделами и отмечается нужным значением.

К чекбоксам, которые олицетворяют собой разделы, также прибиндил команду, в которой проверяются все ли разделы выбраны или только часть и в зависимости от этого меняем значение свойства `IsSelectedAll` на true\false\null.

Загвоздка была в том, чтобы прибиндить команду, которая лежит в VM, а не в классе `Chapter`. Выход был найден:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding ChaptersVM}"ItemsSource="{Binding SiteChapters}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
                                  Path=DataContext.SelectCommand}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}"
                      Margin="5,3,0,2"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```